# How can I check if my concept is sufficient for my function's implementation?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

When I write a template function, I'd like to use concepts, and also to be confident that I haven't used something in my function over and above the "contract" that the concept specifies. See C++ core guidelines [T.10](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#t10-specify-concepts-for-all-template-arguments).

Motivating -- but artificial -- example:

```
template <typename T>
concept maxable = std::totally_ordered<T>; // or require x < y -> bool

template <maxable T>
T max(T x0, T x1, T x2)
{
    T x = x0;
    if (x < x1)
        x = x1;
    if (x < x2)
        x = x2;
    return x;
}
```

`max(0, 1, 2) /*->2*/` is ok but, oops, the following doesn't compile:

```
struct Val
{
    int x{};
    Val(int x) : x(x) {}
    Val(const Val&) = delete;
    auto operator<=>(const Val&) const = default;
};

auto v = max(Val{0}, Val{1}, Val{2});
```

with error `'Val::Val(const Val &)': attempting to reference a deleted function` within the *implementation* of my function on line `T x = x0;`.

I can fix the bug in my concept by adding `std::copy_constructible<T>` upon which the compile error becomes (on MSVC)

```
error C2672: 'max': no matching overloaded function found
could be 'T max(T,T,T)'
note: the associated constraints are not satisfied
note: the concept 'maxable<Val>' evaluated to false
note: the concept 'std::copy_constructible<Val>' evaluated to false
```

This is what I want -- the user gets a warning about a constraint not being satisfied rather than having to look through my implementation. But is there some convenient way to check that I haven't forgotten something in my concept, or, conversely, used something I shouldn't have? I'm assuming that the experts who write std library algorithms must have some way of getting this right -- or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. C++ does not have a reputation for being telepathic and determining what the program's requirements are, and then issue a diagnostic message if the code does not meet the requirements. It's always on the hapless programmer to correctly analyze the code, determine its properties and requirements, and then implement it correctly.

Comment: Happy to take that, or similar, as an answer. This has been bugging me for a while as I tried to introduce concepts into my code, and I couldn't find anything on it when I tried searching for it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik> the compiler sees the implementation and could definitely check that each operation is guaranteed to be available through at least one constraint. It does not do so because the constraint language is turing complete, making it undecidable in the general case. That is a design choice of the constraint feature however, not a universal rule. Some other languages verify constraints - at the cost of limited expressivity of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that it's impossible. C++ does not have so-called *constrained generics*, where the compiler makes sure that nothing more than what your constraints guarantee is usable within a function template.

One of the most common issues is forgetting about constraints for initialization and assignment.
You forgot to account for the copy assignment operator, which is only covered by `std::copyable`.

Here's how to do it properly:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept maxable = std::totally_ordered<T> && std::copyable<T>;

template <maxable T>
T max(T x0, T x1, T x2)
{
    T x = x0;   // call to non-explicit copy constructor (std::copyable)
    if (x < x1) // comparison (std::totally_ordered)
        x = x1; // copy assignment operator (std::copyable)
    if (x < x2) // comparison (std::totally_ordered)
        x = x2; // copy assignment operator (std::copyable)
    return x;   // non-explicit move constructor or copy elision (std::copyable)
}               // OK, function is sufficiently constrained :)
```

However, `max` is arguably over-constrained because we don't need a type to be copyable, and we don't need assignment operators for `max`. With a different implementation, there can be lesser constraints.

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept maxable = std::totally_ordered<T> && std::move_constructible<T>;

template <maxable T>
T max(T x0, T x1, T x2)
{
    return x0 < x1 ? x1 < x2 ? std::move(x2) : std::move(x1)
                   : x0 < x2 ? std::move(x2) : std::move(x0);
}
```

If you selected a reference like `std::max` does, you could even avoid `std::move_constructible`.

#### Conclusion

There are two lessons to be learned:

1. It's extremely difficult not to under-constrain. Gotchas like copy-constructible types with no assignment operators are easily forgotten.
   Note that `std::copy_constructible<T>` also requires `std::convertible_to<T, T>` to account for `explicit` constructors. When designing your own concepts, you also have to remember such details.
2. It's extremely difficult not to over-constrain. There often exists a simpler implementation that doesn't require copyability, or that doesn't require assignment operators. This is problematic because changing constraints affects the ordering of functions in overload resolution, and therefore breaks API.

---

*Note: because copy-initialization requires non-explicit constructors, and because list-initialization may use `std::initializer_list` constructors (which win against copy constructors in overload resolution, by the way), you should prefer direct-initialization when in doubt. `std::copyable` covers copy-initialization, but it's still a good habit to use direct-initialization in function templates.*

Comment: You answered and then some.

Comment: This is a judgment call but imo overconstraining is ok... The constraint is part of the API. Does it make sense for value types? For more resource-like types? You don't want to choose the absolute minimum that works for the current implementation because that constrains future changes. Great answer though

Comment: Yes, relaxing a constraint later is backwards compatible. Tightening one is not.